# How to do POST to Microsoft Graph API with nodejs

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to do a POST, using [request.post](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestmethod), to the Microsoft Graph API as shown below, but the request returns the error

```
err
Error: Argument error, options.body.
```

How can this code be fixed to make the POST work?

```
var request = require('request');
var Q = require('q');

// The graph module object.
var graph = {};

graph.addRow = function(token) {

  request.post(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userid/drive/root:/file.xlsx:/workbook/tables/Table_1/rows/add`, {
    auth: {
      bearer: token
    },
    body: {

      "index": null,
      "values": [
          [ "2020-08-2800:00","3180","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]
      ]
  }
  }, function (err, response, body) {
    var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
});
```

The POST otherwise works, with the same URL and `body`, in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

Comment: console.log body before parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

The POST completes by replacing `body:` in the options object with `message:`, and a new row is added to the Excel worksheet. But none of the values make it.

Was able to add the row by following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/table-post-rows?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript) and using the [Microsoft Graph JavaScript Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript#microsoft-graph-javascript-client-library).